# Can't show my array data in my page from database in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

I hope you're all fine, so I am having a little problem, I am getting data from firebase and I have an array containing an array and I want to show it in my view but I can't, I will write my code and explain what I want to achieve later.

This is the data in my database :

```
posts 
     --- 1 
          --- puslisher -- "Erick" 
          --- content :   "Something is written here"
          --- comments 
                      --- 1
                           --- comment : "Yes"
                           --- commentator : "Patrick"  
                      --- 2 
                           --- comment : "I dont think so "
                           --- commentator : "Sarah"
     --- 2 
          --- puslisher -- "Patrick" 
          --- content :   "News here .."
          --- comments 
                      --- 1
                           --- comment : "Yes"
                           --- commentator : "Ines"
```

I get the data in my app.component.ts :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    pubs:Observable<any[]>;
    constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase){
    }
    ngOnInit(){
       this.pubs = this.getData('/posts');
    }

    getData(path):Observable<any[]>{
       return this.db.list(path).valueChanges()
    }

}
```

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div *nfFor="let post of pubs | async ">
    <p>publisher {{post.publisher}}</p>
    <p>content : {{post.content}}</p>
    <div>{{post.comments}}</div>
    <ul> 
       <li *ngFor="let cmt of post.comments" >{{cmt.comment}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But I am getting an error in my console :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'comment' of undefined
```

But when I write only {{cmt}} instead of {{cmt.comment}}, I get something like this :

```
publisher: Erick
content : Something is written here 

,[object Object],[object Object]

- 
- [object Object]
- [object Object]



publisher: Patrick
content : News here 

,[object Object]

- 
- [object Object]
```

Which means That I am getting my objects but the first one is always empty, I don't know why, and I want to show my comment text.

I hope I well explained my problem, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you check for undefined of cmt and see if it works well? something like cmt ? cmt.comment : ' no data '

Comment: You can see your what is in your object using json pipe like this `{{cmt | json}}`

Comment: Antoine : I tried it and I get the data right I guess, for example I get this one for Patrick's comment : { "comment":"Yes","commentator": "Patrick" }, Do you think that the ' " ' is causing a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) so the template doesn't try to access the properties of the object before it is defined.

Try the following:

```
<li *ngFor="let cmt of post.comments" >{{ cmt?.comment }}</li>
```

Comment: Well, You're right somehow, I am getting my data using your method but I am receiving an additional empty object in the begging of my array, I dont know from where I am getting it but it was the one causing problems, And I still dont know how to solve that.
Thank you for your precious time Sir.

Comment: Glad I could help! Consider accepting and / or upvoting the answer so others know that my answer was helpful (up arrow) or that your question has been answered (check mark). Welcome to SO :)